# How to get Model meta data via API or SQL query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a ML table with the following attributes

[image]

I tried using BigQuery ML [Inspection API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-train)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ML.TRAINING_INFO(MODEL `partitionTables.sample_model`)
```

but none provide in a clear way the desired Model type and Training options information, for example: Model Type or Loss Type

Any ideas on how I can resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Model's Info that you see in UI used to be available in Tables.get API till end 2018. It is not a case since early 2019 and from what I know BigQuery Team is working on `BigQuery Models API` which will allow to get this type of info. I hope someone from BigQuery Team can provide link for alpha of this project (or beta if it is in beta already) - if not you can contact support to get into

Looks like this API is already available - you can check it at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/bigquery/v2/bigquery.models.get

If you run below API

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/cloud-training-demos/datasets/flights/models/ontime?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

you will get response with expected details

```
200

- Show headers -

{
 "etag": "DJnL9iOElEx0e+GH/lX4uA==",
 "modelReference": {
  "projectId": "cloud-training-demos",
  "datasetId": "flights",
  "modelId": "ontime"
 },
 "creationTime": "1528900048363",
 "lastModifiedTime": "1528901292504",
 "modelType": "LOGISTIC_REGRESSION",
 "trainingRuns": [
  {
   "trainingOptions": {
    "maxIterations": "20",
    "lossType": "MEAN_LOG_LOSS",
    "learnRate": 0.1,
    "l1Regularization": 0,
    "l2Regularization": 0,
    "minRelativeProgress": 0.01,
    "warmStart": false,
    "earlyStop": true,
    "learnRateStrategy": "LINE_SEARCH"
   },
   "results": [
    ...
   ],
   "evaluationMetrics": {
    ...
   },
   "startTime": "2018-06-13T14:24:22.620Z"
  }
 ],
 "featureColumns": [
  ...
 ],
 "labelColumns": [
  ...
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail this is exactly what I need

Comment: P.S. Looks like this API was public only few days and is not available since yesterday. Announcement about this API appeared on Release Notes page briefly and then was deleted :o(  I think we should just wait till after Next'19. Btw, are you coming?

Comment: Actually we upgrade to the lates Google api javascript npm and its there https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis. Thanks so much for your help. Unfortunately this year my schedule didn't allowed me to come to Next19 I'll really miss it. Hopefully next year.